# How to create two separate android application projects in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

How to create another android application project in the same android studio which already have a project and an application .
Is it possible to have two separate projects with two separate android applications in the same android studio?

Comment: You can of course have as much projects as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Windows:
Go to: File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Project Opening.
macOS:
Preferences -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Project.

> Check "Open project in new window"...

[image]

Comment: and then ?
choose File > New > New Project ?
or File > New > New Module ?

Comment: File > New > New Project